# Data similarity between values in different sample

Tags: r, clustering, python, dataset

Hello every one I wanted segregate my data into different data set like based on the behaviour of my data looking like as below

```
ID  samp1 samp2 samp3 samp4 samp5 
name1  80    50    20    10    0
name2  30    35    40    30    25
name3  50    100   100   25    90
name4  90    80    50    30    0  
name5  60    40    20    10    5
name6  90    80    20    30    0
name7  28    30    27    30    32
```

wanted subset IDs values across sample based on behavior of the value if values are almost similar in all sample those ids one subset1, names which are having reducing values those into one subset2, and values those which are not in subset1 and subset2

subset1

```
ID  samp1 samp2 samp3 samp4 samp5 
name2  30    35    40    30    25
name7  28    30    27    30    32
```

subset2

```
 ID  samp1 samp2 samp3 samp4 samp5 
name1  80    50    20    10    0
name4  90    80    50    30    0  
name5  60    40    20    10    5
name6  90    80    20    30    0
```

subset3

```
ID  samp1 samp2 samp3 samp4 samp5 
name3  50    100   100   25    90
```

I am not finding any method or logic to segregate this kind of data which is very big and data which values are sample to sample variation is there any one suggest me how can I proceed
Thank you

Comment: Hi, to me, It seems not very clear the criterion used to separate the dataset.

Comment: Try researching clustering methods in whatever programming language you're using.